# Flutter custom page transition animation

Tags: flutter, animation, transition, flutter-animation

I want to have a custom page transition for my splash page described below:

I want the page to be split in half horizontally and the top half to move up and the bottom half to move down and leave the frame.

How can I achieve this? any help or hint is appreciated.